# Custom Permalink Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

my general permalink for posts is: /blog/%postname%/
but this will add a /blog to my custom post types too, they have custom urls like: /help/%postname%/ and etc.. after I added /blog/ to general permalinks all post types has /blog too. like: blog/help/%postname%/

I made with_front false for help post type but its not working…
any idea?

```
    $slugs = [ 
    'help'
    => apply_filters( 'amzshyar_help_slug', 'help' ),
    'category'
    => apply_filters( 'amzshyar_help_category_slug', 'help-category' )
    ];
    register_post_type( $slugs[ 'help' ], array(
        'label'               => _tstr( 'پایگاه دانش' ),
        'description'         => _tstr( 'پایگاه دانش' ),
        'labels'              => array( 'name' => _tstr( 'پایگاه دانش' ), 'singular_name' => _tstr( 'پایگاه دانش' ), 'menu_name' => _tstr( 'پایگاه دانش' ), 'parent_item_colon' => _tstr( 'پایگاه دانش' ), 'all_items' => 'پایگاه دانش', 'view_item' => 'مشاهده مطلب', 'add_new_item' => 'افزودن مطلب جدید', 'add_new' => 'افزودن مطلب جدید', 'edit_item' => 'ویرایش مطلب', 'update_item' => 'بروزرسانی', 'search_items' => 'جستجو', 'not_found' => 'موردی یافت نشد.', 'not_found_in_trash' => 'موردی یافت نشد.' ),
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-editor-help',
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'taxonomies'          => array( $slugs[ 'category' ] ),
    ) );
    register_taxonomy( $slugs[ 'category' ], array( $slugs[ 'help' ] ), array(
            'hierarchical'      => true, 
            'label'             => 'دسته', 
            'singular_label'    => 'دسته', 
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => $slugs[ 'category' ], 'with_front'=> false ),
            'show_admin_column' => true, 'show_ui' => true, 'show_in_rest' => true, 'query_var' => true
        )
    );
```

I also wrote my code up

Comment: Do you want to remove blog from the url of custom post type and also want to add blog in general settings?

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani yes, I just want to remove it from custom post types and keep it for general content